# FOS JS RoutingBundle produces routes for localhost only

Tags: javascript, symfony, fosuserbundle

JS RoutingBundle is generating routes for localhost only.

Why could this be so?

On my dev-server

```
Routing.generate('index');
"/web/app.php/"
```

On my prod-server

```
Routing.generate('index');
"https://localhost/web/app.php/"
```

Note: Neither of these servers are my localhost.

Comment: Are you dumping these to a json file using the command line? If so this may be of some use - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/100 .

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. Firstly your virtual host looks to be configured wrong. Your webroot should be web/ and you should ideally rewrite app.php to hide it.

Secondly, and your actual question: you are probably missing certain parameters in your config so your command line can determine your server name:

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: example.org
    router.request_context.scheme: https
    router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the base url in the file
 fos_js_routes.js (or  fos_js_routes.dev.js)

Change :

```
fos.Router.setData({"base_url":"","routes":{...} ...)
```

to

```
fos.Router.setData({"base_url":"/app_dev.php","routes":{...} ...)
```